# Am getting Bad Request while uploading an Image to the server (backend) , am using xam.plugin.media

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Am trying to upload an image with the help of Xam.plugin.media NuGet package. But am getting a **400 Bad Request**.

Below is my method which uploads the image to the backend.

```
private async void UploadImage()
        {
            var token = Application.Current.Properties["token"].ToString();


            var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();


            var imagFile = _mediaFile.AlbumPath;
            var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagFile);
            ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);

            multiForm.Add(new StringContent("1"), "x");
            multiForm.Add(new StringContent("100"), "y");
            multiForm.Add(new StringContent("100"), "width");
            multiForm.Add(new StringContent("100"), "height");


            multiForm.Add(baContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(_mediaFile.AlbumPath));

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6" +
                "IkpXVCJ9.eyJYwZi05MjhhLTRiZjctYjZkNi0wY2U1ODRkOGRjZmQiLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZ" +
                "SI6IjIwZDA0MDY3LTU3YzYtNGY2MC04ZDI5LTg1NzkxMmFmOWI2MSIsImNsdCI6ImVuLUdCIiwidHoiOiJ" +
                "XLiBFdXJvcGUgU3RhbmRhtZSIsIm5iZiI6MTU1NjQ3NTMyNCwiZXhwIjoxNTU2NDgyNTI0LCJpY" +
                "XQiOjE1NTY0NzUzMjQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLnZpYS5zb2Z0d2FyZSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBz" +
                "Oi8vd3d3LnZpYS5zb2Z0d2FyZSJ9.z5rghA338FDAtoInFYugMgwIirrdl9CrsGKhS8ceoFI");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(utils.Settings.BaseUrl + "/auth/Users/ChangeAvatar", multiForm);

            Debug.WriteLine("--> * "+response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

            Debug.WriteLine("response --> * "+_mediaFile.AlbumPath);
            Debug.WriteLine("--> * " + response);
        }
```

So according to what I have implemented, I thought everything could work out.

Below are the parameters needed by the backend, actually when I try testing the endpoint in postman it works fine, but the method above doesn't work.

[image]

This is what happens on postman everything works fine when I upload an image.

[image]

What could be missing in my code for uploading?

Comment: one is using /Users/ChangeAvatar, the other is using /auth/Users/ChangeAvatar?

Comment: @Jason, actually , there's a base URL for the endpoint, it has **auth** on it , I just didn't include it, let me include it.

Comment: ok, then next I'd suggest looking at the raw request from postman and compare it to the request you're building in C# (look at the actual request object in the debugger)

Comment: @Jason, kindly check out the image for postman , I have updated my question, you can see what the parameter wants and the result with a *200* success status code..

Comment: in your code you are using key "file" for the image data

Comment: So I change this line `multiForm.Add(baContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(_mediaFile.AlbumPath));
` . to this `multiForm.Add(baContent, "image", Path.GetFileName(_mediaFile.AlbumPath));
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the service expects a parameter called "image" but you are passing a parameter named "file"